# Would Typescript solve these backend's environment unpredictable changes?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I was developing a web application some days ago with PHP for backend and Vue for frontend. The developer environment was my PC and everything was working very well, but when I've deployed it to a server, things changed.

In my PC, when a boolean had to be answered by a request, it was returned as an integer 0 or 1. In the production it was returned as string "0" or "1". I know that in javascript I can use the == operator to reach my objective, but my question here is: would Typescript solve this issue?

Comment: You're saying that the data you're getting back (from PHP) is a number in one case but a string in another. No, it doesn't seem like TypeScript would be remotely applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so.

Typescript is a tool that allows you to compile `.ts` code to `.js` code. When doing so -during the compile time-, some potential issues can be catched by the Typescript compiler. For example, during the compilation phase, a Typescript code like:

```
function compute(a: number): number {
    return a * 7;
}

compute('ha');
```

would produce a compilation error, since you're calling `compute` with a string when it expects a number. On top of that, Typescript can provide a really good intellisense.

However, once your Vue application is deployed and running, the real code that your server is sending to the browser in every deployment is **compiled, Javascript code**.

No Typescript thing is on the browser when your app is live and running: so, if some rest API from your server is returning a bad value -i.e. a string instead of a number-, it is the compiled, running Javascript code who has to deal with it.